# Positioning issue with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, dom, html, positioning

I have an application that opens up several windows. The content is dynamically created by the DOM with jQuery, but the classes are static.

The problem is that the bottom div sticks at the bottom of the top div, instead of the bottom (see illustration below).

Is there something obviously i'm missing here?

```
.containerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left:50px;
    top: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.topDiv {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.middlediv {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

.bottomDiv {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This is how it looks:

```
--------------------
      topDiv
--------------------
     bottomDiv
--------------------


     middleDiv


--------------------
```

Comment: What does your html look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` in the `bottom` div's CSS. That's the only way `bottom:0` can work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the concepts of absolute and relative the wrong way round.

position: relative; bottom: 0; means no change from the default. Position the bottom of this element distance 0 relative to where it would be anyway, i.e. no difference at all.